# Sum of Duration from Database Field (Duration)

Tags: php, datetime

I am having issue in SUM of Time or Duration from my Database field.

Suppose. I have 5 Records

```
1. 00:25:32
2. 00:08:52
3. 00:33:22
4. 00:25:30
5. 00:15:12
```

how to sum all the times with `php`.
I spent a lot time on it but failed.

I have tried this.

```
$time = "00:58:30";
$time2 = "00:12:35";

$secs = strtotime($time2)-strtotime("00:00:00");
$result = date("H:i:s",strtotime($time)+$secs);
echo $result;
```

But it not works good for multiple records

Comment: I would convert all desired times to timestamps and add them together. So `$time = strtotime($time1)+strtotime($time2)+....`

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us what you have tried that is not working as expected.

Comment: As per your method I tried this.. 

$time = "00:58:30";
$time2 = "00:12:35";
$time3 = "00:12:35";
$time4 = "00:12:35";
$MainTime = strtotime($time) + strtotime($time2) + strtotime($time3) + strtotime($time4);
$result = date("H:i:s",strtotime($MainTime));
echo $result;

//OutPut = 00:00:00

Comment: updated questions as well. @Dave

Comment: It is fixed... I used Mysqli Query instead of PHP to calculate.

SELECT  SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(`SongDuration`))) AS `TimeSum` FROM `mu_forms_competition_entries`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all of you. I have fixed it. I checked some other question on Stackoverflow and i got answer what i wanted.

```
SELECT  SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(`SongDuration`))) AS `TimeSum` FROM `mu_forms_competition_entries`
```

Comment: When you find an answer to a given question you're expected to close the question and duplicate so it gets linked to the original question. But this doesn't answer current question (how to sum times in PHP).betwewn

Answer (score 0):

Durations are not dates. What would tomorrow at 35:00:00 mean?

The closest builtin feature is [DateInterval](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php), but in order to use it as-is your input data needs some rewriting (`'00:25:32'` into `'PT00H25M32S'`) and I don't think it supports addition anyway.

It isn't difficult to make the calculations yourself (error checking omitted and negative times not considered for brevity):

```
function timeToSeconds(string $time): int
{
    [$h, $m, $s] = explode(':', $time);
    return $s + 60 * $m + 3600 * $h;
}

function secondsToTime(int $seconds): string
{
    return sprintf(
        "%02d:%02d:%02d",
        floor($seconds / 3600),
        floor(($seconds / 60) % 60),
        $seconds % 60
    );
}

$times = [
    '00:25:32',
    '00:08:52',
    '00:33:22',
    '00:25:30',
    '00:15:12',
];
$total = 0;
foreach ($times as $time) {
    $total += timeToSeconds($time);
}
echo secondsToTime($total);
```

If you're allowed to change the database query there's probably a builtin function to convert to seconds right from SQL. For instance, MySQL has [TIME_TO_SEC()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time-to-sec).

Last but not least, if your database actually has a `Time` column type, perhaps it allows to `SUM()` it.